# Форма поверх всех окон в системе (через WinAPI), фокусировка

Tags: c#, winapi, форма

мне нужно сделать прогу, которая будет всегда висеть поверх всех окон windows, даже диспетчер задач не должен перекрывать форму и игры там всякие на подобии тех программ, которые позволяют делать любые окна в системе поверх остальных. Как они это делают. Я пробовал SetWindowPos, но я так понял, что нужно чтобы этот метод вызывался постоянно и ещё SetFocus тоже. Или может есть другой адекватный способ?

Comment: `сделать прогу, которая будет всегда висеть поверх всех окон windows` это нельзя сделать, как минимум потому, что если 2 такие проги запустить, одна всегда будет перекрывать другую

Comment: а вообще для винформ ищите свойство формы `TopMost`

Comment: Игры работают в режиме fullscreen, его перекрыть нельзя, только если не влезать в функции отрисовки DirectX, а некоторые игры за такое "влезание" могут банить за читы.